# Print Absolute Value of the sum of 2 diagonals in matrix (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I am not sure where my error is, but it is not returning anything

```
def diagonalDifference(arr):
left=0
right=0
for i in range(len(arr)):
    left+=arr[i][i]
    right+=arr[i][len(arr)-i-1]
print(abs(left-right))
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to indent the entire function and return something at the end
try:

```
def diagonalDifference(arr):
    left=0
    right=0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        left+=arr[i][i]
        right+=arr[i][len(arr)-i-1]
    print(abs(left-right))
    return abs(left-right) # return after print
```

Comment: Did you call the function? It works for me so you must've forgotten one of those